# How to work with R3D and RMD files? FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, red

I am getting collections of files of the types

```
A0123-random-name.RMD
A0123-random-name.R3D
```

Googling tells me `R3D` is a raw RED file and `RMD` is Red Meta Data - data about the processing to be applied.

Can `ffmpeg` work with these combinations of files? If so, what is an example command line?
If not, what other software can I use to convert these files?

Comment: What software are you editing/working with usually?

Answer (score 7):

R3D files are essentially just a custom container that holds video encoded in JPEG2000 and PCM audio. Though ffmpeg only supports the RED container until version 3, **not** the newer version 4 ([see this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2690)).

You can convert RED version **3** files the same way you would convert any other video with ffmpeg.
F.e. to h264 use the command below. Doesn't make much sense though to use h264 for further editing, you will have to use an intermediate codec and or container that your software supports:

```
ffmpeg -i input.r3d -vcodec libx264 -preset slow output.mp4
```

The usual way though is to use the free REDCINE-X tool provided by RED:
https://www.red.com/downloads?category=Software&release=final

It allows you to transcode your r3d files into pretty much any desirable format as long as its supported by V4W (Video for Windows, e.g. all codecs installed on your system). Or QuickTime on Mac.

Redcine is also the only useful way to do something with the RMD files.

Comment: Redcine-x tool is the good solution for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use red official program "REDline"
Download It from here https://www.red.com/download/redline-linux-beta

It's a shell script. to install it. From properties change it's permission to allow execute.

[image]

Now open it in terminal and install it

```
$ sudo <filelocation/file.sh>
```

if you are in a installer directory you can install it by running

```
$ sudo ./file.sh
```

Now after installing it.

Currently it's a command line program.

normally you can convert R3D (red video files to other formats like openexr,tiff , jpeg ) files to image sequences and also you extract audio too.

Now if i want to convert  a R3D files to jpeg sequences the command would be like this

```
$ REDline -i <filelocation/file.R3D> --format 3 -o filename
```

let me explain what are these commands and options are

here REDline is our program for converting R3D files to image sequences

`-i` means video for converting

`--format 3` means convert to what format currently the program supports DPX , Tiff, OpenEXR , JPEG, SGI, R3D Trim, Apple ProRes and Avid DNX formats. now what does 3 means 3 means convert R3D files to image sequences. so how can you convert to Tiff format use number 1. for other formats you can use

DPX = 0, OpenEXR = 2, SGI = 4, R3D Trim = 102, Apple ProRes=201, Avid DNX = 204

`-o` means output file name because you are converting to jpeg image sequences the program will automatically name it.like wise

```
filename.000000.jpg
filename.000001.jpg
filename.000002.jpg
filename.000003.jpg
```